# Showing image in ImageView after Decoding without Compression

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my android application i am taking image from camera , then i want to encode it without compression.Then after encoding i want to decode and show in image view

Following is the code, with compression and it is working perfectly(image is showing in image view)

```
Bitmap thumbnail;
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 1, bytes);
byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
String ImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,bytarray.length);
imageView11.setImageBitmap(bmimage);
```

But when i use following code image donot showup in imageView. please please please help

```
int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4; 
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
thumbnail.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] b = buffer.array();
String ImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,bytarray.length);
imageView11.setImageBitmap(bmimage);
```

Comment: The code looks good. What if you don't use the Base64 encoding?

Comment: You can just compress using PNG, which is lossless. Quality should stay the same. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)